# suppress warnings related to certain library

Tags: valgrind

How can I tell `valgrind` to stop showing any kind of error related to a certain library? I got lots of reports that look like this:

```
==24152== Invalid write of size 8
==24152==    at 0xD9FF876: ??? (in /usr/lib64/dri/fglrx_dri.so)
==24152==    by 0x110647AF: ???
==24152==  Address 0x7f3c98553f20 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I could prune them by the address (0x7fxxxxxxxxxx is not something that is allocated at userland), but my `valgrind` build seems not to accept `--ignore-ranges=0x7f0000000000-0x7fffffffffff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate suppression-lists using `--gen-suppressions=all`. Then you can add those to some `.supp` file under `lib/valgrind`.